What does it mean col Minei gehinom sholtim bo
BH
Hi, in Igerret HaRamban the Ramban quotes Razal (Nedarim 22a) and says:

כל הכועס כל מיני גיהנם שולטין בו
Anyone who gets angry, all kinds of Gehenna rule over him

What does this mean? Isn’t Gehinom a punishment in the next life? How could someone have punishment here in this world control him if he gets angry?

Why do you assume that the punishment referred to is in this world?

The Rosh on Nedarim 22a offers two explanations:

Anger is as harmful to the body as all the punishments of Gehinnom.
Anger leads to sin, which ultimately condemns the person to Gehinnom.

See the commentaries there for other explanations.

If you rely on the explicit explanation from Ramban in the Chumash, he says that גיהנם is gematria חמס.
That means in context of your text from his letter to his son, to always speak gently toward others. That in so doing, one is freed from anger. That all who indulge in anger, allow all types of violence to rule over them.
